# Veritas BackupExec 9.1 on Windows 2003 R2 x64

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, veritas

Will Veritas BackupExec 9.1 install (and work) on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64?

I know the Agent is supported but I need to install the Veritas Backupexec 9.1 for Windows Server.

Comment: What does Veritas say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have BackupExec 10d and we've verified Symantec will NOT support it on 64-bit, so we haven't even checked if it would install at all. I have my doubts, since BackupExec likes to install its own drivers for devices rather than use the native/vendor ones. 9.1 would be even less able to work on it.